# Fail to clone and run a flutter app from GitHub (Timy-messenger)

Tags: firebase, flutter, github, cmd, clone

I have been trying to clone and run this *time-messenger* app from *GitHub*. But I keep getting this error. I tried `flutter doctor`, `flutter clean`, `flutter build` apk (which also gave an error), `flutter pub cache repair`, `flutter pub get` and so on but it didn't work.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
punreachrany@Punreachs-MacBook-Pro timy-messenger-master % flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86 arm. If you get graphics
artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
                                                                        
Compiler message:
../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_w
idgets-0.20.2/lib/src/platform_scaffold.dart:229:38: Error: The getter
'fullObstruction' isn't defined for the class 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget'.
 - 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget' is from                             
 'package:flutter/src/cupertino/page_scaffold.dart'
 ('../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/page_scaffold.d
 art').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter
or field named 'fullObstruction'.
      final obstruct = navigationBar.fullObstruction == null ||         
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    
../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_w
idgets-0.20.2/lib/src/platform_scaffold.dart:230:25: Error: The getter
'fullObstruction' isn't defined for the class 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget'.
 - 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget' is from                             
 'package:flutter/src/cupertino/page_scaffold.dart'
 ('../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/page_scaffold.d
 art').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter
or field named 'fullObstruction'.
          navigationBar.fullObstruction;                                
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                 
                                                                        
Compiler message:                                                       
../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-0.20.2/lib/src/platform_scaffold.dart:229:38: Error: The getter 'fullObstruction' isn't defined for the class 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget'.
 - 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget' is from 'package:flutter/src/cupertino/page_scaffold.dart' ('../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/page_scaffold.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'fullObstruction'.
      final obstruct = navigationBar.fullObstruction == null ||         
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    
../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-0.20.2/lib/src/platform_scaffold.dart:230:25: Error: The getter 'fullObstruction' isn't defined for the class 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget'.
 - 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget' is from 'package:flutter/src/cupertino/page_scaffold.dart' ('../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/page_scaffold.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'fullObstruction'.
          navigationBar.fullObstruction;                                
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                 
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.                                                           
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* Where:                                                                
Script '/Users/punreachrany/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 882
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.              
> Process 'command '/Users/punreachrany/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 9s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         9,7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
punreachrany@Punreachs-MacBook-Pro timy-messenger-master %
```

What can I try next?
Project Link : https://github.com/janoodleFTW/timy-messenger

Comment: can you please provide the link to your mentioned github project ?

Comment: https://github.com/janoodleFTW/timy-messenger

Answer (score 0):

Change the version number of `flutter_platform_widgets` to `^0.32.4` in `pubspec.yaml`, then run `flutter packages upgrade`

[Source](https://github.com/janoodleFTW/timy-messenger/issues/33#issuecomment-578706645)